# "FirebaseError: Invalid authentication credentials provided" error when setting up google sign in on Android

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth-2.0, firebase

I've been trying to set up a google login for my app.

I followed the tutorial here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

I did everything. I can sign in sign in and sign out.

Then I added an Async task to get a token, which it seems to successfully retrieve. It is implemented as follows:

```
private class GetIdTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


            private static final  String SERVER_CLIEdNT_ID = "749433126040-ca4gfj7ucuh0m2suo3230u03o3d7doni.apps.googleusercontent.com";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            Account account = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIEdNT_ID; // Not the app's client ID.
            try {
                return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account, scopes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
                return null;
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving ID token. Google exception", e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ID token: " + result);
            if (result != null) {

                idToken = result;

                Toast.makeText(context, "token is " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else {
                // There was some error getting the ID Token
                // ...
                Toast.makeText(context, "token is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

So after running the method and getting the token, I then run the generic firebase code to connect to Firebase (having already set up a google app, put the client ID in firebase, enabled it etc.) I got the code from https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/google.html

And implemented it as follows:

```
 public void loginFireBase() {


    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://boiling-fire-944.firebaseio.com");
    ref.authWithOAuthToken("google", idToken, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {


        @Override
        public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
            // the Google user is now authenticated with your Firebase app

            Toast.makeText(context, "user succesfully authenticated with firebase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, idToken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
   ///////THIS IS THE PART WHERE THE ERROR IS GENEREATED  FROM//////////

            Log.v("firebase problem", firebaseError.toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, "I'm an authenticated error" + "id Token was " + idToken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
}

}
```

So ultimately, I login, I get a token, and then pass it to the firebase authWithOAuthToken method, and then I get the error:

> FirebaseError: Invalid authentication credentials provided.

Can anyone see any problems in my code? I have a feeling the token is not valid but can't find a way to check its validity.

Tell me if you need me to post more, I was trying to keep it brief.

Thanks to anybody who can help !

Comment: It looks like you're getting the wrong token type from Google. See this link for how the Firebase Android Login demo retrieves the token: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/samples/logindemo/GoogleOAuthActivity.java#L94-L95

Comment: Ahhhhhh, amazing  - It's registering successfully now ! Thank you so much for that dude. I had a feeling it was a token problem, but I didn't know which other ones to try. I feel the documentation is a little ambiguous with regard to the type of token in that it only reads:  "you will need a Google OAuth access token returned by the login flow provided by the Google+ SDK". I have one more cheeky question. Do you know if the users once authorised are automatically added to the database? Thanks again !

Comment: User data is not automatically added to your Firebase database. If you want such data to be stored, you can store it when the user authenticates. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing

Comment: Fantastic, I'll do that,  thanks again ! I accepted your answer below. Cheers dude.

Comment: GooglePlus signin is now deprecated (with the push of google to decouple + from all other services after they did the opposite just a few years ago :P). I wonder if this works with the new recommended Google SignIn api https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Comment: Found the anwer: Micah, you should probably edit your question at the top to point to this post for the new google signin flow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631750/firebase-and-new-google-sign-in-on-android/33662260#33662260

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever I need to authenticate with Firebase on Android, I go back to the [Firebase Android login demo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android/). Here's how that app [gets the OAuth token for Google authentication](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/samples/logindemo/GoogleOAuthActivity.java#L94-L95):

```
String scope = String.format("oauth2:%s", Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN);
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                                GoogleOAuthActivity.this, 
                                Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), 
                                scope);
```

It looks like you're getting the [cross-client id for the user](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth), which is not a valid OAuth token.

**Update (20160308)**: nowadays I instead look at the [FirebaseUI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), which includes this functionality and is more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was having this error message in `Firebase/Crash`

the solution was run this line:

`rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*`

this was happening because previously already had generated the `ServiceAccount.json` file and restart the credentials needed