# Firebase and new Google Sign-In on Android

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

I'm trying to add support for the [new Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) announced as part of Play services 8.3.0. 
I successfully configured the project and I'm getting a token from the GoogleApiClient, but Firebase is returning an
 `Invalid Credentials error`
 when calling 
`ref.authWithOAuthToken("google", token)`

Google+ sign-in is working but that requires a separate permission which is a pain when developing for Marshmallow.
[Firebase android tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/google.html) has a Google+ sign-in sample and my feeling is that they dont' have support for the new Google Sign-In yet.

Has anyone tried the new Google Sign-In in connection with Firebase and got it to work?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247959/google-play-games-firebase-and-the-new-google-sign-in/41499987#41499987

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's a mix of the steps in [Add Sign-In to Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) and [Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth).

Once you have a `GoogleSignInResult` you can get the account name from that and then request the token with the minimal scopes:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        String email = acct.getEmail();

        // TODO: run an async task to get an OAuth2 token for the account
    }
}
```

The async task will need to request these scopes:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String scopes = "oauth2:profile email";
    String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), email, scopes);
    // exception handling removed for brevity
    return token;
}
```

Now you can use the token to sign in to Firebase as usual:

```
ref.authWithOAuthToken("google", token, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {...
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring that out! I created a pull request to update the Firebase login demo to work without Google+:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android/pull/21

Comment: I'm getting a `BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.google.android.gms.auth.TokenDat` at `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)`. What could be wrong?

Comment: Oh, it was just a ProGuard/DexGuard problem. `-keep public class com.google.android.gms.auth.** { public *; }` did help.

Comment: Ah, that explains. Might be worth asking as a separate question and self-answering, so that others can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Great answer! You're an angel @BogdanM.

Comment: `getToken` with `accountName` is now deprecated. Any other solutions?

Comment: This is a great solution but I find the only way to get it to work is to use "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN  which generates a much more "scary" permissions request popup. Any ideas why the plain "oauth2:profile email" do not work?

Comment: The snippet I posted doesn't use `PLUS_LOGIN` and works. If you're having problems, post a new question that includes a [minimum, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've done.

Comment: thanks Frank, i think there was some issue with some cached state on my device and the account. after i cleared all perms on the account and cleared app cache, your solutions started working. thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247959/google-play-games-firebase-and-the-new-google-sign-in/41499987#41499987

Answer (score 0):

Download source code from here ([Firebase Google Login Android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/04/03/firebase-google-login-android/)). In this blog I have provided the screenshot also for your help.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:src="@drawable/profileimage"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"></View>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:id="@+id/tv_email"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"></View>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#E02F2F"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/iv_google"
            android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_google"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sign in with Google"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.deepshikha.googlepluslogin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    ImageView iv_google;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ImageView iv_image;

    boolean boolean_google;
    TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_google;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        listener();

    }

    private void init() {

        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_google = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_google);
        iv_google = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_google);
        iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("LoginActivity", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("LoginActivity", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(user);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(MainActivity.this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }

    private void listener() {
        iv_google.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_google.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.iv_google:
                break;
            case R.id.tv_google:
                if (boolean_google){
                    signOut();
                    tv_name.setText("");
                    tv_email.setText("");
                    boolean_google=false;
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.profileimage).into(iv_image);
                }else {
                    signIn();
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }

    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        try {

            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("LoginActivity", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("LoginActivity", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]

                        try {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void signOut() {
        // Firebase sign out
        try {
            mAuth.signOut();

            // Google sign out
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        try {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (user != null) {
            String str_emailgoogle = user.getEmail();
            Log.e("Email", str_emailgoogle);
            tv_email.setText(str_emailgoogle);
            tv_name.setText(user.getDisplayName());
            boolean_google=true;
            tv_google.setText("Sign out from Google");

            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load( user.getPhotoUrl()).into(iv_image);


            Log.e("Profile", user.getPhotoUrl() + "");

        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```