# How to make Firebase work with the new Google SignIn flow?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, firebase, google-signin

This is how I construct the google sign in options.

```
Builder builder = new Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestIdToken([myclientidhere])
```

From the builder I get the GoogleSignInOptions which I later on use to successfully obtain a signin result. Then from it I extract the access token as such but I get

```
firebase.authWithOAuthToken(FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER, 
  checkNotNull(signInResult.getSignInAccount().getIdToken()),
   new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() { ...
```

This returns an error "Invalid authentication credentials provided."

I've verified that when I use the IdToken for a google app engine endpoints authentication it works fine so I know the way I pass the client id is fine (at least for google). Do I potentially need extra scopes?

---

The reason I prefer the new SignIn flow over the old account-one is three fold: the old one is deprecated + the new one requires fewer permissions + it provides cross-device silent signin.

Comment: Found the answer here. Not sure how to close this question as a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631750/firebase-and-new-google-sign-in-on-android/33662260#33662260